# Display: table on IE6/IE7

Tags: css, internet-explorer

How to fix display: table on IE6/IE7 without using htc file or code in javascript but simply with the css?

Comment: Who cares about IE6/7? What's about IE5.5, does it works? :/

Comment: I feel bad for you son.

Comment: Don't cater to IE6 users. The more you pamper them, the longer they will stick around, thinking that everything is still fine. Don't let them nag you. Stand firm and tell them they will keep having these problems until they upgrade.